# Spider Chart in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have a requirement to develop a spider chart in any of SSRS 2008 above versions.
please look into the below image and me if have any work around.

Thanks in Adv.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should be able to do it using radar chart. More detailed explanation is available at [MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/e112a735-051c-4913-8e59-94144e02751f/)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Visual Studio 2017]

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and data tools and the spider chart (Polar or Radar as Microsoft calls it) is in place.

You would Need to place the following options on the chart:

- Patents - As Chart Values
- Vitamin Results - As Category Groups

Edit:

Use Radar chart. On each data set that appears on the chart, set transparent background and thick border. That would be somehow what you ask for.